# Wifi not working after suspend. No previously followed methods worked

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend

I use Ubuntu 16.04 and wifi is disabled after suspend. Solutions such as restart network manager did not work.

Thank you in advance, A

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://igtek.tk/index.php/2016/05/11/fix-ubuntu-16-04-no-wireless-connection-after-suspend/):

> Step 1: Create a new script in the `systemd` `system-sleep` folder.
>
> ```
> sudo nano /lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset_network.sh
> ```
>
> Step 2: Copy and paste the following into the newly created script.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> if [ $1 = post ] && [ $2 = suspend ] then 
>     service network-manager restart 
> fi
> ```
>
> Step 3: Exit nano by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and save it.
>
> Step 4: Make the script executable.
>
> ```
> sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/reset_network.sh
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.
On the other hand, this method doesn't work in my occasion as what it does is simply execute "service network-manager restart" command automatically which as I mentioned does not work in my case